# Can a folder be part of two git repositories?

Tags: git, repository, git-subtree

I started working on a project and I realized that part of the project would be a great library to put up on Bitbucket/Github for others to use. The problem is that the entire project is under a personal repository so I'm not sure how I would make part of my personal repository a new repository that points to the public repository so I can make the change in one place and have it update both repositories. Please note that the public repository is only *part* of the personal repository, so I cannot simply add the public repository as a remote because that will push the entire project to the public repository, which I don't want.

Any help/ideas/tips would be appreciated. I've tried using git subtrees before, but have always gotten confused by the intent of subtrees and also how to use them properly. If this scenario is possible using the subtree technique, I would love to know. Thanks.

Comment: See http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules and http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging